# Commands in discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How would you make a command that only people with a certain role can use, has a 5 hour cooldown per user, and the command takes a line from a .txt file and dms that string to the user that ran the command, and deletes it from the .txt file?

Edit: Sorry im new to this, i only started learning yesterday and im still dumb
If you can and want to help me please add me on discord ParrotSecurity9#0175

Comment: Ask one thing at the time, we won't just write all of your code for you :)

Comment: There are a lot of good tutorials out there. Just search for them and follow them. If you still have questions you can ask them , show some code that you tried and you will get answers. Also reading the documentation is helpful: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in the API docs for [discord.ext.commands.has_role()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.has_role) and [discord.ext.commands.cooldown()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_permissions#discord.ext.commands.cooldown)
Both can be used as [decorators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators)